# WSO2 endpoint format

Tags: wso2, endpoint

new to WSO2 but trying to do something that should be relatively straightforward even for the uninitiated, before I have a crack at some xslt mediation in a wso2 proxy.

All im trying to do as a first step is change the transport between the wso2 client (jms) and the endpoint (http). The client is sending a full soap envelope in the JMS payload.
I can see that my endpoint is being invoked from the server logs (however I can see requests are rejected). 
Sure enough, I can see from the proxy logs that WSO2 is adding an additional SOAP envelope wrapper around the soap payload from the client.

My understanding is that this should be correctable by setting the format attribute of the endpoint to "leave as-is".  This doesnt make a difference however.  I suspect this is an easy endpoint or proxy configuration fix, rather than requiring some xsl mediation?  Any guidnace gratefully received:

my code:

Endpoint:

```
    <endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <address uri="http://d26li228.au.alcatel-lucent.com:44006/ilws/InstantLinkSOA">
      <suspendOnFailure>
         <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
         <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>
   </address>
</endpoint>
```

Proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="McProxy3"
       transports="McJMS"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="enable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint key="conf:/ilepr"/>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">McQueue</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the content type of the message you are receiving from JMS : if there is already a SOAP Envelope, it's text/xml :

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
    <rules xmlns="">
        <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
        <default>text/xml</default>
    </rules>
</parameter>
```

If the service you're calling through your endpoint wait soap11 or soap12, you can set this format in your endpoint definition (don't let "leave as-is")

You've defined OUT_ONLY to true inside your inSequence, before sending your message through your endpoint : the ESB won't instanciate any callback and will not receive any response (outSequence will never be executed)

Comment: thanks for your pointer Jean-Michel.  This has triggered another gremlin however.

Comment: Sorry, hit the save button too soon -  your follow-up (on setting the format explicitly to soap12) was spot on as it pre-emptively solved the next unsupported content type error reported by the server! thanks again.